# Angular ReactiveForms FormArray removeAt removes all elements in the FormArray

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am creating a form that consists in two `FormArray`s, `items` and `savedItems`.
On each element in the form array there is a button that can remove that element from the array.

The top/first `FormArray` is populated from a list of objects. While the second `FormArray` is for the user to fill.

The problem is, on the first `FormArray` whenever I click on the "Remove Entry" button all elements in the `FormArray` are removed instead of the element belonging to (in the same position) the "Remove Entry" button.

Here is my form definition:

```
<form [formGroup]="boxForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(boxForm)">
<div class="row" formArrayName="savedItems" *ngFor="let item of getSavedItems.controls; let i = index;"  >
  <div *ngFor="let trailer of trailerModelList; let x = index;" >
    <div class="form-group" [formGroupName]="i" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
      <div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
          <label for="name">Origin</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="From" value="{{trailer.fromLocation}}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
          <label for="name">Destination</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="To" value="{{trailer.toLocation}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="{{trailer.name}}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="removeSavedItem(i)">Remove Entry</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row" formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of getItems.controls; let i = index;" >
  <div class="form-group" [formGroupName]="i">
    <div class="col-md-5 form-group" >
      <label for="name">Origin</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="origin" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 form-group">
      <label for="name">Destination</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="to">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="removeItem(i)">Remove Entry</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"  style="margin-right: 10px">Go</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="addItem()" style="margin-right: 10px">New Box</button>
```

And here is how I create, add and remove items for the `FormArray`:

```
get getItems(): FormArray {
  return this.boxForm.get('items') as FormArray;
}

get getSavedItems(): FormArray {
  return this.boxForm.get('savedItems') as FormArray;
}

createBox(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
    origin: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]],
    to: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]]
  });
}

addItem(): void {
  this.getItems.push(this.createBox());
}

removeItem(index) {
  this.getItems.removeAt(index);
}

removeSavedItem(index) {
  this.getSavedItems.removeAt(index);
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2wmnsa) with a reproducible code of my issue. If you click on any "Remove Entry" above the horizontal bar both entries will be removed from that element in the `FormArray` instead of only the selected one.

Why is this happening? I am quite sure it is related to having two for loops. One for the savedItem controls and an inner loop to loop over the elements in my list to populate the `FormArray` but I cannot pinpoint the issue, I am still learning my way with Angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the creating your `FormArray`-property `savedItems`, also this line:

```
...
savedItems: this.formBuilder.array([this.createBox()])
...
```

This lines means, that you define only one `FormGroup` in your `FormArray` and so you have one element with `index = 0`.

In your template file you in block for `savedItems` you have two loops:

1.) `*ngFor="let item of getSavedItems.controls; let i = index;"`

This is right loop and will give your right functionality for `removeAt`.

2.) `*ngFor="let trailer of trailerModelList; let x = index;"`

This is wrong loop, because you can not create `FromArray`-items from template, so as you have now.

**Problem in short:** By clicking on `Remove entry`-button both(all) `savedItems` will be removed from array, because you have only one element with index = 0 in `FormArray`.

**Solution:**

**Step 1:** Create for each `trailerModelList`-item an `FormArray` with `createBox()`-method.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.boxForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: this.formBuilder.array([this.createBox()]),
      savedItems: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });

    this.trailerModelList = new Array();
    this.trailerModelList.push(new TrailerModel(1, 'test', 'London', 'Paris'));
    this.trailerModelList.push(new TrailerModel(2, 'test2', 'Amsterdam', 'Berlin'));

    this.trailerModelList.forEach(item => {
      (this.boxForm.get('savedItems') as FormArray).controls.push(this.createBox(item.name, item.fromLocation, item.toLocation));
    });
  }

....

  createBox(name: string = null, origin: string = null, to: string = null): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [name, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      origin: [origin, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]],
      to: [to, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]]
    });
  }
```

**Step 2:** Remove following loop from template: `*ngFor="let trailer of trailerModelList; let x = index;"`

**Step 3:** Add `formControlName`-property to your form items inside this loop: `*ngFor="let item of getSavedItems.controls; let i = index;"`

```
<div class="row" formArrayName="savedItems" *ngFor="let item of getSavedItems.controls; let i = index;"  >
      <div>
        <div class="form-group" [formGroupName]="i" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
          <div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
              <label for="name">Origin</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="From" formControlName="origin"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
              <label for="name">Destination</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="To" formControlName="to" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="removeSavedItem(i)">Remove Entry</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zr2qb3) with working solution.